# Can't use Jackson in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jackson, jsoup

I've downloaded

> jackson-core-2.4.0-20140316.193819-27.jar

from Jason download page, 
then added it to Java Build Path - Library & Order and Export. 
But I can't use ObjectMapper class (ObjectMapper cannot be resolved ....) 
I'm using jdk 7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's expected. ObjectMapper is part of the [jackson-databind](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind) artefact.

Answer (score 1):

please download these jars -
jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar
jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar
jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar
jackson-core-2.2.3.jar

and let me know. you can use maven to get better result.

Comment: jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar and jackson-core-2.2.3.jar --start downloading these jars first and please try. then you can download rest of the jars and carry on.